# How to remove Group Column Prefix from dx-data-grid grouping?

Tags: jquery, devexpress

I'm using [dx-data-grid](https://js.devexpress.com/Demos/WidgetsGallery/Demo/DataGrid/RecordGrouping/jQuery/Light/) with Jquery and i'm trying to remove the grouping prefix from the grouping panel but it seems like it's not possible.
As you can see in the picture - the prefix is the column name, now, i can remove it by setting the caption to empty string, but then i'm still remaining with the colon sign, obviously i just want to display the state name.

Here is what i want to remove :

[image: Here is what i want to remove :]

Here is with caption set to empty string :
[image: Here is with caption set to empty string :]

Here is a piece of the code that creates the  grid:

```
$(function(){
var dataGrid = $("#gridContainer").dxDataGrid({
    dataSource: customers,
    allowColumnReordering: true,
    showBorders: true,
    grouping: {
        autoExpandAll: true,
    },
    searchPanel: {
        visible: true
    },
    paging: {
        pageSize: 10
    },  
    groupPanel: {
        visible: true
    },
    columns: [
        "CompanyName",
        "Phone",
        "Fax",
        "City",
        {
            dataField: "State",
            groupIndex: 0
        }
    ]
}).dxDataGrid("instance");

$("#autoExpand").dxCheckBox({
    value: true,
    text: "Expand All Groups",
    onValueChanged: function(data) {
        dataGrid.option("grouping.autoExpandAll", data.value);
    }
});
});
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/roy_barak/pen/eYNRexe)

Answer (score 2):

You need to use "groupCellTemplate".

There my angular 8 code:

```
<dx-data-grid [dataSource]="Items">
  <!-- Before columns -->
  <dxi-column dataField="value" [groupIndex]="0"
              groupCellTemplate="groupCellTemplate">

    <div *dxTemplate="let data of 'groupCellTemplate'">
      <span>{{data.displayValue}}</span>
    </div>
  </dxi-column>
  <!-- After columns -->
</dx-data-grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

For the jQuery variant, add that to the column definition of the data grid:

```
..., {
  dataField: "group",
  groupIndex: 0,
  groupCellTemplate: function(el, data) {
    el.text(data.value);
  }
}, ...
```